# Need a regex expression to get value between two tags

Tags: java, regex, perl

Need regular expression to extract the values between >xxxxx<. Can anybody help me in this.

```
<ChangeID type="String">C10286</ChangeID>
<ChangeID type="String">C10296</ChangeID>
```

Is it possible to get the two values in a comma separated format like **C10286,C10296** in a single regex expression?

Thanks and Regards

Riyas Hussain A

Comment: in which language? and also, regex doesn't change the string, or reformat the string.

Comment: Regex can easily pull out all of the values from the tags as captures, but I believe you are going to need to iterate the captures to assemble the final output.  Also, do you only need the contents of the one tag or do you need it for multiple different tags?

Comment: @Kent: perl or Java. Both are fine for me. Also its not a must to get in comma separated. If its possible to get those values in a single expression is fine. I will do a work around in my automation tool to get them separated.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
(?<=>)[^<]*
```

test it with `grep -Po`:

```
kent$  echo '<ChangeID type="String">C10286</ChangeID>
<ChangeID type="String">C10296</ChangeID>'|grep -Po '(?<=>)[^<]*'
C10286
C10296
```

Comment: Perfect. Its working with Java. Thank you very much Kent for your help.

Comment: I am getting the output as C10286C10296. Is it possible to get them as comma separated in the same expression?

Comment: @user2091573 as I said in comment, reformat string is not the job of regex.

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to lookup for all words and remove the ones we don't need (in case you have more than 1 value inside your tag):

```
(?!ChangeID\b)(?!type\b)(?!String\b)\b\w+
```

You can try it out on : http://regexpal.com/